# Core Location Help!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uialertview, core-location

I need help with core location. I want the user to be able to toggle the core location in settings and I want a UIAlertView to popup saying The App wants to use your current location. Allow or Don't allow. And I wan't to put this on a specific tab. How do i do this and where do i put it?

Also I already have a map setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to do anything of that yourself.
The moment you start asking for location information:

```
CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[manager startUpdatingLocation];
```

iOS will ask the user for confirmation and put your app into the list of apps under location services.

Please read about the basics of CoreLocation, simply in the documentation for CLLocationManager.

Comment: +1 because the OP clearly doesn't care about accepting correct answers. 

@Daniel Christmas - Go back through your question history and click the checkbox next to correct answers. You and the answerer will get some points, and people will be WAY more inclined to go out of their way to help you.